# Android Studio: use string from EditText in SQLiteDatabase rawQuery

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Currently I'm developing a mobile application in Android Studio (Java). I want to make a SQLite-database with account information of users. To log in, the user credentials (username + password) need to be verified. In order to do this, I want to compare the string from an EditText with the credentials stored in the database. When the user touches/presses the button the method 'check' is called. Down below, you can see how this works (in the MainActivity):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView TV1,TV2;
EditText et_username, et_password;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TV1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV1);
    TV1.setText("Please fill in your username and password.");
    TV1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    TV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV2);
    TV2.setTextColor(Color.RED);

    et_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_username);
    et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_password);

    db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Account(" +
            "account_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "username TEXT NOT NULL," +
            "password TEXT NOT NULL);");

    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ('Simon','123');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ('Bart','abc');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Account (username,password) VALUES ('Sytze','lol');");
}

public void check(View view){
    String username = et_username.getText().toString();
    String password = et_password.getText().toString();

    Cursor resultSet = db.rawQuery("SELECT username,password FROM Account WHERE username='" + username + "';", null);
    resultSet.moveToFirst();

    String gbTest = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("username"));
    String wwTest = resultSet.getString(resultSet.getColumnIndex("password"));

    resultSet.close();

    String res = gbTest + " : " + wwTest;
    TV2.setText(res);

    /*
    if (password.toString() != wwTest){
        TV2.setText("Wrong combination...");
    }
    */
}
}
```

When I press the button I get an error (i.e. the app crashes). However, when I replace the 'username' in the resultSet.rawQuery with an actual username in the database, like 'Bart', it does work. Apparently, there is a difference between the string of the EditText and an actual string. How does this come, and why can't I use the string of the EditText? I hope my problem and question are clear, but if not: please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Greets,
Sytze

EDIT
This is the error I get:

```
06-21 15:29:34.194 2114-2114/sytzesimonse.databaseapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:275)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17749)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17749) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
                                                                        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:427)
                                                                        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                        at sytzesimonse.databaseapp.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:56)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270) 
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17749) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5473) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:854) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670) 
                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please define crashes

Comment: Can you specify the message in console when the app crashes?

Comment: Rawquery + editText = SQL Injection.

Comment: Sorry! I added it.

Comment: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0, which means that your query is returning 0 results. Check if your username is good, and is in the database. Use `String username = et_username.getText().toString().trim();` on the username string just in case.

Comment: The database is returning empty set... did you enter the exact username value?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies! With the advice of Vucko I solved it :) It seems that trim() did the job.